# Elixir: how to maintain Stream state across multiple pipes?

Tags: stream, elixir

**My goal**: I want to read the first line of a file, restructure the input in a pipeline, and then process the rest of the file in another pipeline.

**My problem**: The Stream resets on each new pipeline.

**Example code**:

```
defmodule StrangeStream do
  fs = File.stream!("file.txt")

  Stream.take(fs, 1) |> Enum.to_list() |> IO.inspect()

  Stream.take(fs, 1) |> Enum.to_list() |> IO.inspect()
end
```

**Text file `file.txt`**:

```
First line.
Second line.
Third line.
```

**Output**:

```
["First line.\n"]
["First line.\n"]
```

As you can see, the Stream resets in each pipeline. Each pipeline starts from the first line in the file. How do I maintain the state of the stream between calls to a pipeline? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks to Aleksei for setting me on the right course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** you can’t.

---

There is no mutable state in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), hence it’s impossible to maintain a state of the resource.

The only similar thing would be to [suspend](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enumerable.html#reduce/3-examples) the enumerable during reducing, but even this is not possible directly with streams.

You can resort to [`Stream.transform/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#transform/4) and maintain the state yourself, choosing the pipeline accordingly.

*Sidenote:* `Enum.to_list/1` already terminates a stream, so the approach in the question would not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got the effect I wanted. Hope it helps others who look into this.

Again, many thanks to Aleksei for saving me so much time.

```
defmodule StrangeStream do
  do_stuff = fn(something) ->
    # We'd do something useful here
    something
  end

  {:ok, file} = File.open("file.txt", [:read, :line])

  # Read the first line
  first_line = IO.read(file, :line)
  |>  String.trim()
  |>  do_stuff.()
  |>  IO.inspect([label: "first_line"])

  # Create side-effect streams
  print_stream = IO.binstream(:stdio, :line)
  file_stream  = File.stream!("output.txt", [:write, :append])

  # Convert IO to Stream and process
  IO.stream(file, :line)
  |>  Stream.map(&String.trim(&1))
  |>  do_stuff.()
  |>  Stream.into(print_stream, fn(s)-> s <>"\n" end)
  |>  do_stuff.()
  |>  Stream.into(file_stream)
  |>  do_stuff.()
  |>  Enum.to_list()
  |>  IO.inspect([label: "rest of file"])
end
```

**Output**

```
first_line: "First line."
Second line.
Third line.
rest of file: ["Second line.", "Third line."]
```